# string split function is not working as desired

Tags: java

I am trying to split date with milliseconds and print in my format, but having index out of bound exception. It is working in case of split("/") but not with split(".").

I don't know why this is happening.

Code is:

```
public class c {

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    Date date=new Date();                                                                    
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF");                   
     System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

     String a=formatter.format(date);
     String b[]=a.split(" ")[0].split("/");
     String x1=(Integer.parseInt(b[2])-2000)+b[1]+b[0];
     System.out.println("date part is : "+x1);
     String c[]=a.split(" ")[1].split(":");
     System.out.println(c[0]);
     System.out.println(c[1]);
     System.out.println(c[2]);
     System.out.println(c[2].trim().split(".")[0]);// exception at this line
     System.out.println(c[2].trim().split(".")[1]);
     String x2=c[0]+c[1]+c[2].split(".")[0]+c[2].split(".")[1]+"";
     System.out.println("time part is : "+x2);
}
}
```

Log is:

```
08/10/2013 12:02:18.002
date part is : 131008
12
02
18.002
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0   at c.main(c.java:22)
```

Comment: as @Tichodroma pointed out, changing `"."` to `"\\."` should do the trick, but...

... your code is terrible ! Why do you even bother doing all those concatenation and split jugglings, while there are very simple accessors that you can use in the `Date` class ?

Comment: @Orabîg The accessors on `Date` are all deprecated.

Comment: Well, ok, but using a SimpleDatFormat and extract informations from the resulting string.. Does it sound a better idea than using the basic Data accessors ? I don't think so (imho)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`java.lang.String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expressions as the argument.

A single dot `.` is the regular expression for 'any character'. So you split you input after every character.

Escape the dot:

```
split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(".") to split the string by "."

str.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("."));

Answer (score 0):

try not to split... u can always use this formatter.day | .month | .hour or so on....